# Submit Form data with "action='/action'" and associate a method for that action in the controller - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, post

I always worked with J2EE plateform and now I should develop an application using ASP.NET technology.
I know that we can send form data using different actions in J2EE. Then we can associate a method to this action in the controller.

Example;

```
// html form
<form id="postToURL" action="/GenerateExcel">
       // Some form data to send
</form>

-------------------------------------------------------
@RequestMapping(value = "/GenerateExcel", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView someMethod(){
    // some code
}
```

My question is how can I do the same in an ASP.NET application with a method like this;

```
 /* .NET Annotations */
 public virtual ActionResult GenerateExcel(string data)
 {
    // Some Code.....
    // System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CSVTO EXCEL ACtion intercepted");
    // .................
 }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the following if it's same controller scope:

```
<form method="post" action="<%= Url.Action("GenerateExcel") %>" id="postToURL">
    // Some form data to send
</form>
```

Otherwise you have to define the controller of the action:

```
<form method="post" action="<%= Url.Action("GenerateExcel", "ControllerName") %>" id="postToURL">
    // Some form data to send
</form>
```

Furthermore you can define, that your action only accepts `POST` requests like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult GenerateExcel(string data)
{
  // Some Code.....
  // System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CSVTO EXCEL ACtion intercepted");
}
```

You probably won't need the `virtual` keyword here, if you don't want to override the method in a derived class.